# Xcode 5 Installation?

Tags: xcode

Currently, my Mac runs macOS 10.11.6; which doesn't allow the latest Xcode app and I can't update the OS anymore for some reason.

Now, I know it may seem backwards, but I want to download Xcode 5 because I'm familiar with Objective-C and I received an iOS development book from a friend, so no more excuses for me. So, please, any tips are very much appreciated.

Comment: An iOS development book that works with Xcode 5 is terribly out of date and most of what you learn will be very out of date as well.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. This question isn't a great fit for this site, but since you're new I'll try to give you some help.

You should be able to go the Apple developer side, find the downloads section, and look for a button labeled "other downloads". That's where Apple keeps older developer tools. I'm not sure if they go back as far as Xcode 5 however. (We're currently on Xcode 9.4, with Xcode 10 due to be released very soon.) Major version updates are a big deal, and Xcode 5  is >4 (and soon to be 5) major releases out-of-date.

BTW, it looks like Xcode 5.x doesn't support Swift at all. Looking at [**this Wiki article**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#5.x_series) it appears that Swift isn't supported until Xcode 6.0.

What is the model of your Mac?

Also note that Swift changed radically from version 1 to version 2, and made another major switch between version 2 and version 3. Version 4 wasn't as huge a change, but still significant. I suspect Xcode 6.x only supports Swift 1, and at this point learning Swift 1 would be counterproductive. You'd be better off figuring out how to upgrade your Mac to a current OS, or buying a newer used Mac. You're dealing with history trying to use development tools that old. The language and the platforms have changed a **great deal** since then.

Answer (score 0):

In case XCode 5 is not available, you will have to try and update your OS if XCode9 is not compatible with your current OS.

Up until recently, you couldn't update your MacOS beyond a certain version that was tied into what model of Macbook you had.

However, there are ways around it as described here
https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-install-macos-sierra-on-older-mac-3654960/

You should read it carefully and backup your Mac before proceeding. You should also figure out if your WIFI card is compatible as it will not work with certain models

> Installing macOS High Sierra via the Patch Tool will stop Wi-Fi
>   working if your Mac has a Broadcom BCM4321 module - which includes
>   certain configurations of the MacPro3,1, MacBook5,2, MacBookPro4,1,
>   iMac8,1, Macmini3,1, and MacBookAir2,1.